# \verb in label or pin of a tikz node

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, labels, verbatim

The documentation of tikz gives following example containing the `\verb` command  in the node text (Section 2.21 *Adding Text*, v3):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0.5,0.5) node [fill=yellow!80!black]
                       {Text at \verb!node 1!}
     -- (1.5,1.5) node {Text at \verb!node 2!};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If I want to use the label or pin functionality for nodes, it does not work as expected:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0.5,0.5) node [fill=yellow!80!black]
                       {Text at \verb!a_b!}
                     -- (1.5,1.5) node[label={\verb!a_b!}] {Text at \verb!a_b!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The error message given is `! Missing $ inserted.` due to the `_` I want to use.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} \DefineShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}
\SaveVerb{Verb}|a_b|
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
    \draw (0.5,0.5) node [fill=yellow!80!black]{Text at |a_b|} -- (1.5,1.5) 
                    node[label=\UseVerb{Verb}] {Text at |a_b|};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I really do not fully understand what's going on but I can offer a workaround. To this end, let me first mention that creating a new `\savebox` and trying it to fill with `\savebox\verbox{\verb!a_b!}` fails. However, a `lrbox` works, so I propose to store the content of the label in a `\savebox` first and then use it.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\newsavebox\verbox
\begin{document}
\begin{lrbox}{\verbox}
\verb!a_b!
\end{lrbox}
% fails:
%\savebox\verbox{\verb!a_b!}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0.5,0.5) node [fill=yellow!80!black]
                       {Text at \verb!a_b!}
                     -- (1.5,1.5) node[label={\usebox\verbox}] {Text at \verb!a_b!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround producing same output as in @marmot answer.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\draw (0.5,0.5) node [fill=yellow!80!black]
                       {Text at \verb!a_b!}
                     -- (1.5,1.5) node[label=\texttt{a\string_b}] {Text at \verb!a_b!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\texttt{a\_b}` should also work

Comment: @Herbert this is what I had done initially but notice that it does not give same result in OT1 default encoding.

Comment: I cannot see a problem with `\_$\_$`

Comment: @Herbert try it out with tt font. I told you it gives different result, and I don't see why I would have said so if not.

Comment: With OT1 encoding and `A\texttt{\_}$\texttt{\_}\mathtt{\_}$` I get with `pdflatex` three identical underline

Comment: @Herbert I think we have a quiproquo here. I am talking about comparing `\string_` with `\_`. Notice that the OP is asking for `\verb|a_b|`. You can reproduce same with `\texttt{a\string_b}` not with `\texttt{a\_b}` in OT1 encoding.